# Internet is working over Wi-Fi but Google Play Store says "reconnect" after few minutes

Tags: google-play-store

I have a problem connecting to Google Play Store with some Wi-Fi. 
My Wi-Fi at home works fine and I don't see any problem with other sites. But whenever I go to Google Play Store, it just keeps me waiting for a couple of minutes and says "reconnect".

I tried connecting to another Wi-Fi and it works. Then I tried using other phone on my Wi-Fi and it works fine.

It seems only my Zenfone 2 doesn't work on my Wi-Fi. I tried some simple steps I've read on forums like changing time, sync, toggle Wi-Fi and Airplane mode but nothing worked.

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: Try going to Google Play's apps settings (the details will depend on what version of Android you're using) and tap the Clear Cache button. Do the same for Google Play Services.

Comment: @JoeSewell that won't help when the device is working fine on a different network (neither won't changing time). // Carlo: when you're logged-in to your home WiFi, can you reach Google Play using a web-browser (i.e. is it just the playstore app that cannot)? Could it be some "firewall"/"parental controls" on the router blocking the site ***for this device*** (it could be setup device/IP specific)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Wi-Fi router with your existing network modem:

1. Turn DHCP mode to **none** in your Wi-Fi router

   - Login to your router configuration panel from computer
   - Turn **DHCP mode** to **none** in Local Network settings
2. Connect your incoming network cable (from modem) to LAN port instead of WAN port of the Wi-Fi router (we are going to bridge the network; reboot router if necessary)

   - You should know the DHCP IP address range in your modem (usually 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.254)
   - Use one IP address from that range (say 192.168.1.2) for your Wi-Fi LAN interface IP address (Wi-Fi router configuration IP address will be changed to the new one you have opted for)
   - Save changes and reboot your modem

This fixed my connection problem.