# Android 4.4.2, Google Play Store error: No connection, but pages loads fine in browser

Tags: google-play-store

The Android version is 4.4.2. When I open Google Play Store, it says "Error, no connection"But when I open browser I can load pages like `Google.com`.

I tried clearing cache, logging with other Google account, but it isn't working.

Any ideas to resolve the issue?

EDIT: I downloaded Anututu and it says that there is root access..

Comment: I haven't opened Google Play on this phone before..It just shows that error message..Also youtube isn't blocked..

Comment: going through this answer might help you

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/108967/cant-connect-to-google-play/116688#116688

Comment: It happened to me when I did factory reset, solved after upgrading the play store, go to the play store settings scroll down and click on version number it will update to the latest version of play store

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue once too when flashing a custom ROM. Download an Play Store apk for Android 4.4.2 and install that.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to **Settings > Applications** and finding **Google Play Services**. Clear the cache and force stop the app. If that doesn't work, try clearing data instead of cache and then force stopping it.

Comment: I can't clear the data, also I can't Force stop it, because I can't press the button..Clearing cache didn't help.. :\

Comment: Sounds strange: If you cannot clear its data, have you setup a Google account at all (and if so, when)? Is the "uninstall updates" button enabled (also check this for the *Google Play Store* app)? For how long are you using the device already?

Comment: Yes, I've logged in my google account. I tryed clearing the data from Google Play Store app, and force stopping it, but it didn't work..There is no button uninstall updates..The device is new, from 1 day.